# Invalid Target Error for my Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

Suddenly I am getting this invalid target issue for my Angular project when I run:

> npm start
> An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid target: {"project":"agmbs","target":"build","configuration":"development"}.
> See "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-w19EiV\angular-errors.log" for further details.

In this angular-errors.log file:
[error] Error: Invalid target: {"project":"agmbs","target":"build","configuration":"development"}.
at C:\Work\angular\dev\myproj\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:175:23
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

The file architexct.js reads:

```
"use strict";
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google LLC All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.Architect = void 0;
const core_1 = require("@angular-devkit/core");
const rxjs_1 = require("rxjs");
const operators_1 = require("rxjs/operators");
const api_1 = require("./api");
const jobs_1 = require("./jobs");
const schedule_by_name_1 = require("./schedule-by-name");
const inputSchema = require('./input-schema.json');
const outputSchema = require('./output-schema.json');
function _createJobHandlerFromBuilderInfo(info, target, host, registry, baseOptions) {
    const jobDescription = {
        name: target ? `{${(0, api_1.targetStringFromTarget)(target)}}` : info.builderName,
        argument: { type: 'object' },
        input: inputSchema,
        output: outputSchema,
        info,
    };
    function handler(argument, context) {
        // Add input validation to the inbound bus.
        const inboundBusWithInputValidation = context.inboundBus.pipe((0, operators_1.concatMap)((message) => {
            if (message.kind === jobs_1.JobInboundMessageKind.Input) {
                const v = message.value;
                const options = {
                    ...baseOptions,
                    ...v.options,
                };
                // Validate v against the options schema.
                return registry.compile(info.optionSchema).pipe((0, operators_1.concatMap)((validation) => validation(options)), (0, operators_1.map)((validationResult) => {
                    const { data, success, errors } = validationResult;
                    if (success) {
                        return { ...v, options: data };
                    }
                    throw new core_1.json.schema.SchemaValidationException(errors);
                }), (0, operators_1.map)((value) => ({ ...message, value })));
            }
            else {
                return (0, rxjs_1.of)(message);
            }
        }), 
        // Using a share replay because the job might be synchronously sending input, but
        // asynchronously listening to it.
        (0, operators_1.shareReplay)(1));
        // Make an inboundBus that completes instead of erroring out.
        // We'll merge the errors into the output instead.
        const inboundBus = (0, rxjs_1.onErrorResumeNext)(inboundBusWithInputValidation);
        const output = (0, rxjs_1.from)(host.loadBuilder(info)).pipe((0, operators_1.concatMap)((builder) => {
            if (builder === null) {
                throw new Error(`Cannot load builder for builderInfo ${JSON.stringify(info, null, 2)}`);
            }
            return builder.handler(argument, { ...context, inboundBus }).pipe((0, operators_1.map)((output) => {
                if (output.kind === jobs_1.JobOutboundMessageKind.Output) {
                    // Add target to it.
                    return {
                        ...output,
                        value: {
                            ...output.value,
                            ...(target ? { target } : 0),
                        },
                    };
                }
                else {
                    return output;
                }
            }));
        }), 
        // Share subscriptions to the output, otherwise the the handler will be re-run.
        (0, operators_1.shareReplay)());
        // Separate the errors from the inbound bus into their own observable that completes when the
        // builder output does.
        const inboundBusErrors = inboundBusWithInputValidation.pipe((0, operators_1.ignoreElements)(), (0, operators_1.takeUntil)((0, rxjs_1.onErrorResumeNext)(output.pipe((0, operators_1.last)()))));
        // Return the builder output plus any input errors.
        return (0, rxjs_1.merge)(inboundBusErrors, output);
    }
    return (0, rxjs_1.of)(Object.assign(handler, { jobDescription }));
}
/**
 * A JobRegistry that resolves builder targets from the host.
 */
class ArchitectBuilderJobRegistry {
    constructor(_host, _registry, _jobCache, _infoCache) {
        this._host = _host;
        this._registry = _registry;
        this._jobCache = _jobCache;
        this._infoCache = _infoCache;
    }
    _resolveBuilder(name) {
        const cache = this._infoCache;
        if (cache) {
            const maybeCache = cache.get(name);
            if (maybeCache !== undefined) {
                return maybeCache;
            }
            const info = (0, rxjs_1.from)(this._host.resolveBuilder(name)).pipe((0, operators_1.shareReplay)(1));
            cache.set(name, info);
            return info;
        }
        return (0, rxjs_1.from)(this._host.resolveBuilder(name));
    }
    _createBuilder(info, target, options) {
        const cache = this._jobCache;
        if (target) {
            const maybeHit = cache && cache.get((0, api_1.targetStringFromTarget)(target));
            if (maybeHit) {
                return maybeHit;
            }
        }
        else {
            const maybeHit = cache && cache.get(info.builderName);
            if (maybeHit) {
                return maybeHit;
            }
        }
        const result = _createJobHandlerFromBuilderInfo(info, target, this._host, this._registry, options || {});
        if (cache) {
            if (target) {
                cache.set((0, api_1.targetStringFromTarget)(target), result.pipe((0, operators_1.shareReplay)(1)));
            }
            else {
                cache.set(info.builderName, result.pipe((0, operators_1.shareReplay)(1)));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    get(name) {
        const m = name.match(/^([^:]+):([^:]+)$/i);
        if (!m) {
            return (0, rxjs_1.of)(null);
        }
        return (0, rxjs_1.from)(this._resolveBuilder(name)).pipe((0, operators_1.concatMap)((builderInfo) => (builderInfo ? this._createBuilder(builderInfo) : (0, rxjs_1.of)(null))), (0, operators_1.first)(null, null));
    }
}
/**
 * A JobRegistry that resolves targets from the host.
 */
class ArchitectTargetJobRegistry extends ArchitectBuilderJobRegistry {
    get(name) {
        const m = name.match(/^{([^:]+):([^:]+)(?::([^:]*))?}$/i);
        if (!m) {
            return (0, rxjs_1.of)(null);
        }
        const target = {
            project: m[1],
            target: m[2],
            configuration: m[3],
        };
        return (0, rxjs_1.from)(Promise.all([
            this._host.getBuilderNameForTarget(target),
            this._host.getOptionsForTarget(target),
        ])).pipe((0, operators_1.concatMap)(([builderStr, options]) => {
            if (builderStr === null || options === null) {
                return (0, rxjs_1.of)(null);
            }
            return this._resolveBuilder(builderStr).pipe((0, operators_1.concatMap)((builderInfo) => {
                if (builderInfo === null) {
                    return (0, rxjs_1.of)(null);
                }
                return this._createBuilder(builderInfo, target, options);
            }));
        }), (0, operators_1.first)(null, null));
    }
}
function _getTargetOptionsFactory(host) {
    return (0, jobs_1.createJobHandler)((target) => {
        return host.getOptionsForTarget(target).then((options) => {
            if (options === null) {
                throw new Error(`Invalid target: ${JSON.stringify(target)}.`);
            }
            return options;
        });
    }, {
        name: '..getTargetOptions',
        output: { type: 'object' },
        argument: inputSchema.properties.target,
    });
}
function _getProjectMetadataFactory(host) {
    return (0, jobs_1.createJobHandler)((target) => {
        return host.getProjectMetadata(target).then((options) => {
            if (options === null) {
                throw new Error(`Invalid target: ${JSON.stringify(target)}.`);
            }
            return options;
        });
    }, {
        name: '..getProjectMetadata',
        output: { type: 'object' },
        argument: {
            oneOf: [{ type: 'string' }, inputSchema.properties.target],
        },
    });
}
function _getBuilderNameForTargetFactory(host) {
    return (0, jobs_1.createJobHandler)(async (target) => {
        const builderName = await host.getBuilderNameForTarget(target);
        if (!builderName) {
            throw new Error(`No builder were found for target ${(0, api_1.targetStringFromTarget)(target)}.`);
        }
        return builderName;
    }, {
        name: '..getBuilderNameForTarget',
        output: { type: 'string' },
        argument: inputSchema.properties.target,
    });
}
function _validateOptionsFactory(host, registry) {
    return (0, jobs_1.createJobHandler)(async ([builderName, options]) => {
        // Get option schema from the host.
        const builderInfo = await host.resolveBuilder(builderName);
        if (!builderInfo) {
            throw new Error(`No builder info were found for builder ${JSON.stringify(builderName)}.`);
        }
        return registry
            .compile(builderInfo.optionSchema)
            .pipe((0, operators_1.concatMap)((validation) => validation(options)), (0, operators_1.switchMap)(({ data, success, errors }) => {
            if (success) {
                return (0, rxjs_1.of)(data);
            }
            throw new core_1.json.schema.SchemaValidationException(errors);
        }))
            .toPromise();
    }, {
        name: '..validateOptions',
        output: { type: 'object' },
        argument: {
            type: 'array',
            items: [{ type: 'string' }, { type: 'object' }],
        },
    });
}
class Architect {
    constructor(_host, registry = new core_1.json.schema.CoreSchemaRegistry(), additionalJobRegistry) {
        this._host = _host;
        this._jobCache = new Map();
        this._infoCache = new Map();
        const privateArchitectJobRegistry = new jobs_1.SimpleJobRegistry();
        // Create private jobs.
        privateArchitectJobRegistry.register(_getTargetOptionsFactory(_host));
        privateArchitectJobRegistry.register(_getBuilderNameForTargetFactory(_host));
        privateArchitectJobRegistry.register(_validateOptionsFactory(_host, registry));
        privateArchitectJobRegistry.register(_getProjectMetadataFactory(_host));
        const jobRegistry = new jobs_1.FallbackRegistry([
            new ArchitectTargetJobRegistry(_host, registry, this._jobCache, this._infoCache),
            new ArchitectBuilderJobRegistry(_host, registry, this._jobCache, this._infoCache),
            privateArchitectJobRegistry,
            ...(additionalJobRegistry ? [additionalJobRegistry] : []),
        ]);
        this._scheduler = new jobs_1.SimpleScheduler(jobRegistry, registry);
    }
    has(name) {
        return this._scheduler.has(name);
    }
    scheduleBuilder(name, options, scheduleOptions = {}) {
        // The below will match 'project:target:configuration'
        if (!/^[^:]+:[^:]+(:[^:]+)?$/.test(name)) {
            throw new Error('Invalid builder name: ' + JSON.stringify(name));
        }
        return (0, schedule_by_name_1.scheduleByName)(name, options, {
            scheduler: this._scheduler,
            logger: scheduleOptions.logger || new core_1.logging.NullLogger(),
            currentDirectory: this._host.getCurrentDirectory(),
            workspaceRoot: this._host.getWorkspaceRoot(),
        });
    }
    scheduleTarget(target, overrides = {}, scheduleOptions = {}) {
        return (0, schedule_by_name_1.scheduleByTarget)(target, overrides, {
            scheduler: this._scheduler,
            logger: scheduleOptions.logger || new core_1.logging.NullLogger(),
            currentDirectory: this._host.getCurrentDirectory(),
            workspaceRoot: this._host.getWorkspaceRoot(),
        });
    }
}
exports.Architect = Architect;
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,......
```

Specifically, architect.js:175:23 is as below:

```
function _getTargetOptionsFactory(host) {
    return (0, jobs_1.createJobHandler)((target) => {
        return host.getOptionsForTarget(target).then((options) => {
            if (options === null) {
                throw new Error(`Invalid target: ${JSON.stringify(target)}.`);
            }
            return options;
        });
    }, {
        name: '..getTargetOptions',
        output: { type: 'object' },
        argument: inputSchema.properties.target,
    });
}
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be becuase of invalid project name in some of the auto generated files in your angular project. You might have renamed the project name and the name might not have got changed in some of the default locations. I got the same problem and I found the old project name in `angular.json`, so make sure the project name appears correct in `angular.json`, as shown below (code snippet). In addition I changed the name in `karma.conf.js` under `coverageReporter`, also search for any other instaces of project name in anyother files and replace them.

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "xxxnewprojectname": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      }
      ....
      ..
      ..
        }
            }
    }
```